# как сделать так чтобы этот код запускался при нажиме на кнопку.И при повторном нажиме код останавливался

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

мой код:

```
const myImg = document.querySelector('.myImg');

        let i = 0;
        setInterval(() => {
            if (i == 4) {
                i = 0;
            }
            myImg.setAttribute('src',`./img/img${i}.jpg`);
            myImg.setAttribute('alt',`img${i}`);
                i++;
        }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
let enableTimer = false;
let timer = null;

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    enableTimer = !enableTimer;
    
    if (!enableTimer) {
        clearInterval(timer);    
        return;
    }
    
    let i = 0;
    timer = setInterval(() => {
        console.log('Вывод в консоль: ' + (++i));
    }, 500);         
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">clickMe</button>
```

Вот код, запускающийся по кнопке и останавливающийся. Добавить свой код в него не должно составить труда.

Comment: у меня возникли некоторие трудности можете помочь?

Comment: у меня не останавливается при повторном нажимание

Comment: Нужен полный ваш код....хотя бы на jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q75xdf38/2/

Comment: @olooliver где там хоть что-то из того, что я для примера написал в ответе?

Comment: я просто незнаю как зделать так как в примери,поэтому решил сделать из click (не получилось). Я был бы очень благодарен если вы мне помогли

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myImg = document.querySelector('.myImg');
let intervalId
let i = 0

const intervalHandler = () => {
        if (i === 4) {
            i = 0;
        }
        myImg.setAttribute('src',`./img/img${i}.jpg`);
        myImg.setAttribute('alt',`img${i}`);
        i++;
}

function onKeyDown() {
    myImg.addEventListener("onkeydown", () => {
        intervalId = setInterval(intervalHandler, 2000)
    })
}

function onKeyUp() {
    myImg.addEventListener("onkeyup", () => {
        clearInterval(intervalId)
    })
}
```

Comment: ваш код не роботает